# Debugging Tools/Skills with NAT

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, nat

**When facing below situation what debugging tools/skills can we use to solve the problem?** See the flow, we use port forwarding in NAT2 whose type is Symmetric so that the client can communicate with Server. When session between client and server is established, the client can send files to the server via TCP connections. The upload bandwidth is around 2Mbit/s.

The issue is while the client is uploading files to server, we found at some point all the TCP connections will be blocked, the server can't receive any packets from those TCP connections anymore so that all the tcp connections will be dropped by server application because of timeouts. NAT2 is a SO simple router that we can't capture packets from it, to get rid of this issue what can we do?

```
     Client  ----- NAT1  ---Internet----- NAT2 ----- Linux Server
```

**UPDATE**
Problem also exists in below topology. In this topology, the NAT between client and Linux server is also the NAT2 other than a different one, because the client use DNS name to access Linux server, thus all packets from client will go through NAT2 to the internet, but will come back to NAT2 again and be sent to LINUX Server by Port Forwarding in NAT2.

Here is another question: if there is some application persisting in sending packets to the forwarding port (we set Port Forwarding in NAT2, and suppose the port Number is PortN), then can it cause all the tcp connections which receive packets via this PortN to be blocked or to receive no packets within 3-5 minutes?

```
     Client  ----- NAT2  ---Internet----- NAT2 ----- Linux Server
```

Comment: Is replacing NAT2 with a new router an option? I ask because it's certainly a cheaper option than investing in network taps.

Comment: @selbie Not sure, it depends on the company. If the router you said is cheap enough I consider to buy one myself for studying later, but not this moment.

Comment: @StevePeng Right when the TCP connections are blocked, are any packets sent to the server? For example TCP Reset?

Comment: @KristianEvensen not sure at the moment, we plan to capture all packets from the server tomorrow. Are there any other debugging skills available except capturing packets from server? Suppose the server doesn't receive any packets from the NAT2 then what can we do?

Comment: That is a good question. Since everything works fine in downlink direction, but not uplink, perhaps you could try to send data in both directions (as a test). There could be a traffic threshold you don't meet. However, I find the behavior of NAT2 strange. I thought that as long as a TCP connection is active, NATs will keep the mapping.

Comment: I was a bit quick. I see now that you have configured static port forwarding to reach the server. Then NAT2 should only do destination NAT, and might not even keep TCP state (depending on configuration). Have you checked that NAT1 is well-behaved?

Comment: @KristianEvensen - A NAT will drop a TCP connection (lose its port mapping) if there isn't any activity on the channel. TCP keepalives aren't always sufficient.

Comment: @selbie I thought about that, but since he mentions uploading data, I assume the amount of traffic would be higher than some threshold.

Comment: @selbie how much is this timeout value when a NAT decides to drop a tcp/udp mapping?

Comment: All NATs are different. But in practice, we use 45 seconds to send a custom keep-alive in the absence of traffic.